# summary to a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, summary

Using `summary(var)` gives me the following output:

```
PAY_BACK_ORG    
 Min.   : -16.40  
 1st Qu.:   0.00  
 Median :  26.40  
 Mean   :  34.37  
 3rd Qu.:  53.60  
 Max.   :4033.40
```

I want it as a `dataframe` which will look like this:

```
Min     -16.40
1st Qu    0.00
Median   26.40
Mean     34.37
3rd Qu   53.60
Max    4033.40
```

How can I get it in?

Comment: Is `var` a `data.frame` with one column? Please make your example fully reproducible.

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
var <- rnorm(100)
x <- summary(var)
data.frame(x=matrix(x),row.names=names(x))
##                x
## Min.    -2.68300
## 1st Qu. -0.70930
## Median  -0.09732
## Mean    -0.00809
## 3rd Qu.  0.71550
## Max.     2.58100
```